# JavaFX FXMLLoader getController NullPointerException

Tags: javafx, nullpointerexception, controller, fxml, fxmlloader

I have a project in school where I have to develop a program where you first can choose whether you want to save/read to/from a SQL DB or to save/read to/from XML.

I've made a GUI where you can choose between both methods.

The GUI closes after the user clicks on one of the buttons and the MainMenu GUI opens.
Now I need to know in the `MainMenuController` what the user choose.
I found online a Method to call the `MainMenuController` inside the first controller, with `FXMLLoader.getController()`.

```
try {                       
    Stage stage = new Stage();
    FXMLLoader Loader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent root = Loader.load(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));

    MainMenuController mc = Loader.getController();
    mc.setSave("sql");

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

MainMenuController

```
public class MainMenuController {   
    private String save = null;

    public void setSave(String save) {
        this.save=save;
    }
    public String getSave() {
        return save;
    }
}
```

But when i try to access a method in `MainMenuController` I get a `NullPointerException` for

```
mc.setSave("sql")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ,to understand this issue ,you should make some tricks to detect where is your problem.When you do :

```
 System.out.println(mc);
```

You will find the result is `null`.So you can not call `setSave("sql")` with `null` object,you got a null controller because your did not specify the location of your file,but you can change some lines to resolve your problem :

```
 try {
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            FXMLLoader fxm = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));

            Parent parent = (Parent) fxm.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(parent);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            FirstController mc = fxm.getController();
            System.out.println(mc);
            mc.setSave("sql");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the *static* method [`FXMLLoader.load(URL)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.net.URL-). Because this is a static method, it has no effect on the state of the `FXMLLoader` instance you created; specifically the controller field is not set.

Instead, set the location on the `FXMLLoader` instance, and call the *instance* method [`load()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load--):

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));
// or just FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));

Parent root = loader.load();
```