# Cannot seem to instantiate a non-null FXMLLoader

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, fxml

I have read a few of the related posts on this topic but have been unable to use them to solve my issue. I believe my failure is one of comprehension and not that I am facing a unique issue. But, I am at a total impasse.

I'm building a CRUD application using JavaFX. One of my application's buttons, "Import Data," is throwing NullPointerExceptions:

```
// *a button that opens a new window with a textField where the user can paste text data*
@FXML
private void importDataButton(ActionEvent event) {
    // *load the fxml file*
    URL viewLocation = getClass().getResource("/importView.fxml");
    // *get the file's controller*
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    ImportController importController = loader.getController();
    importController.setMainController(this);
    loader.setLocation(viewLocation);

    try {
        loader.load();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        System.out.println("IO Exception thrown.");
        return;
    }
....
}
```

I'm not very good with IntelliJ's debugger yet, but I've used it to determine that the FXMLLoader object is null. So when

```
importController.setMainController(this);
```

executes, a NullPointerException is thrown because the object *this* refers to is null. I...think. So then

```
ImportController importController = loader.getController();
```

cannot retrieve the controller from the FXMLLoader object (loader).

For reference, setMainController() is in another class called ImportController, and that method's code is as follows:

```
public void setMainController(MainController mainController) {
    this.mainController = mainController;
}
```

**Things I've tried:**

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813995/javafx-fxmlloader-getcontroller-nullpointerexception) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23461148/fxmlloader-getcontroller-returns-null), both of them recommend that I must run loader.load() [given FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader()] in order to retrieve data from the object. However, I've tried this, and I just get errors upon errors: InvocationTargetExceptions and IllegalStateExceptions. I have also tried instantiating an FXMLLoader object that is non-null, using

```
FXMLLoader load = new FXMLLoader(getClass.getResource("sample.fxml"));
```

But it seems to have no effect on the content of the object (and yes, I am replacing "sample.fxml" with my filename.)

I hate to make a similar post, but I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Just to add some background: The reason `getController` returns null if called before `load` is because, when using `fx:controller`, it is the responsibility of the `FXMLLoader` to instantiate an instance of the controller class—which doesn't happen until loading the FXML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `loader.getController()` before `loader.load()`. That's why your `importController` is null when calling `importController.setMainController(this)`.

Call `loader.load()` first:

```
URL viewLocation = getClass().getResource("/importView.fxml");
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(viewLocation);

try {
    loader.load();

    ImportController importController = loader.getController();
    importController.setMainController(this);
} catch (IOException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

But be aware that the `initialize()` method in your `ImportController` is called before `setMainController()`.